# How to pass variable from jquery to code behind (C#)?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, variables, code-behind

Here is my code, but it doesn't work (code behind gets empty string):
`

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Pass Javascript Variables to Server</title>
     <script type="text/javascript">             // Second Step
         function f() {
             $("[id$='inpHide']").val("My JavaScript Value");

         }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="SetHiddenVariable()">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>  
        <input id="inpHide" type="hidden" runat="server" />  
        <asp:Button ID="btnJSValue" Text="Click" runat="server" OnClientClick="f"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were couple of issues in your code. The parenthesis were missing while calling `f` function in `onClientClick` and if the element has id you can just use the id to select it with `#`

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Pass Javascript Variables to Server</title>
     <script type="text/javascript">             // Second Step
         function f() {
             $("input[id*='inpHide']").val("My JavaScript Value");
         }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>  
        <input id="inpHide" type="hidden" runat="server" />  
        <asp:Button ID="btnJSValue" Text="Click" runat="server" OnClientClick="f()"/>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: His input is `runat="server"`. In this example the ClientID will be "inpHide", but in a real world case it may be inside other naming container. I guess that's why he used the end-with syntax  `$("[id$='inpHide']")`

Comment: @Nickolay - It was already part of your code snippet. It will execute that method on page load. I have removed it now since you are not aware of that method so need of it.

Comment: Looking at his markup it is quite simple but yest if it inside a control or master page it should be client id.

Comment: `*=` will search within the id, it should work fine. Can you check what is the id of this input element when it is rendered on the page.

Comment: View source of the page. Right click on the page and just click on view source or view page source whatever option you could see.

Comment: Or else for now try to use `$("#inpHide").val("My JavaScript Value");`

Comment: Try this then `$("#inpHide").val("My JavaScript Value");`

Comment: No, also doen't work. I think problem not in syntax. May be problem in   jQuery code was updating the label but clicking the button caused the page to post the form data back to itself so my jQuery change was lost

Comment: Yes, on click of the button the page is going to `postback`. However when you read `inpHide` textbox value in the code behind you will get `"My JavaScript Value"`

Comment: if after $("input[id*='inpHide']").val("My JavaScript Value");           set alert("something") it doesn't call alert...

Comment: It should call `alert` and then submit the page. Can you put before that line and see?

Comment: If put before it calls alert.

Comment: Have you included jquery js file on the page?

Comment: No, which jquery also need? jquery.min.js?

Comment: The core jquery js file. You can include it from here    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: Need only jquery-1.4.1.js without jquery-1.4.1.min.js it works

Comment: Folks - can you take this over to a chat room, you all have enough rep.

Answer (score 1):

Your `<input>` tag needs a name attribute, or it won't be posted.

Answer (score 0):

The response from Sean McMillan is right, but I think you also need to change this :

```
<asp:Button ID="btnJSValue" Text="Click" runat="server" OnClientClick="f"/>
```

to

```
<asp:Button ID="btnJSValue" Text="Click" runat="server" OnClientClick="f();"/>
```

Comment: Are you sure your `f` function is being called? If you put an `alert` into it?

Comment: if after $("input[id*='inpHide']").val("My JavaScript Value"); set alert("something") it doesn't call alert... –

Comment: Then your line is causing an error, check the error console in firefox (ctrl+shift+J).