# How to pass int from jquery to c# code block in a view

Tags: c#, jquery

I use Jquery to get the id of a clicked image, and i am successfully able to get this id. However i want to use this id to call this image again from the database using a c# code block. Jquery code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.thisImage', function () {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

This is the code i am using to then call again the image:

```
int id = // the image of the clicked image should be passed over to this int id's value. 

using (The_Factory.Models.The_FactoryDBContext db = new The_Factory.Models.The_FactoryDBContext())
{
  if (db.Treasures.FirstOrDefault(treasure => treasure.treasureID == id).itemImage != null)
  {
    byte[] chosenImage = db.Treasures.FirstOrDefault(treasure => treasure.treasureID == id).itemImage;
    string imageSource = "";
    string imageBase = Convert.ToBase64String(chosenImage);
    imageSource = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase);


    <img id="thisImage" src="@imageSource" width="100" height="100" />
  }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to make a call to the server to do this. The C# code is not actually part of the page once it reaches the browser, it's simply used to generate the HTML.

Comment: @Rob jsfiddle please?

Comment: @LuluthoMgwali You have to use $.ajax and post that id to your web method. Yes, this can't be done through jsfiddle.

Comment: @LuluthoMgwali you can use ajax to do that

Comment: Here is link on Stackoverflow and that is what Rob mentioned also ..[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997810/how-to-pass-variable-from-jquery-to-code-behind-c)