# How do I pass value from a javascript function to C# Code behind?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a dynamic button which have unique **id**'s, I'm getting the id of the clicked button like so:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    //I want to pass this.id to my btnDetails_Click event in C# or to a variable Property(for efficiency)
});
```

How do I do this? Sorry noob in javascript.

Comment: there are too many answers on this question - do you search it first ? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Basp.net%5D+pass+variables+to+code+behind

Comment: thanks, couldn't find it awhileago

Comment: the idea is that you use a hidden input control, you place there the variable with javascript and then is posted on code behind

Comment: yes i've read it somewhere, i just don't know how to call that hiddenfield is it the same as

idOfHiddenFIeld = this.id;?

Comment: If `btnDetails_Click` is already attached to the button, you can use the `sender` parameter of the event handler to retrieve the button and its ID.

Comment: what do you mean by attached? AAAAAAAAAAAAAAH I GOT CONFUSED!

Comment: I must go now, later I post an answer and an example. Do you use jQuery ?

Comment: I'm using ASP.Net C# but, the only thing that can fix my problem now is surely javascript. I just simplified my question, coz I might have to much detail if I go through what I really want

Comment: What is `btnDetails_Click`? You talk about it in your code sample.

Comment: it's an asp.net button. So my exact point here is, When I click on the html button, I want to fire that btnDetails_Click event, BUT, I also want to get the ID of the html button that was clicked, since i have dynamic html buttons created with unique ID's

Comment: The buttons are created in code-behind (C#)?

Comment: yes it's created using StringBuilder like so:

Comment: html.Append("<button id=\"" + dr["ID"].ToString() + "\" type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-primary btn-xs\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#myModal\" runat=\"server\"><i class=\"fa fa-eye\"></i></button>");

Comment: Do you use ASP.NET WebForms or MVC?

Comment: WebForms with Master page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114283/discussion-between-connorsfan-and-jc-borlagdan).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variable from jquery to code behind (C#)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997810/how-to-pass-variable-from-jquery-to-code-behind-c)

Answer (score 2):

I won't code precisely for you, but maybe what I will include could help and point you to right direction in your own conclusion.

Okay, let us say that the page you are using is called Page.aspx, and the method is called Done

```
   var values = {"0,","1","2"};
   var theids = JSON.stringify(values);

   // Make an ajax call
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "Page.aspx/Done",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: {ids: theids },
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (result) {
         alert('Alright, man!');               
     },
     error: function (result) {
         alert('Whoops :(');
     }
 });
```

Comment: hmm sorry, really newbie here, where's the part I passed the id of the button that was clicked?

Comment: Well, as I said I won't code precisely for you -- but, in the code that I posted info is brought from the javascript function via JSON datatype (if you do not know what that is, please research) to something else. In order to do this, you need to use POST method with AJAX. So, implement the post method with AJAX on the click of your button, and tell it where to go. No one will do everything for you in life !

Comment: I get what you're saying coz I do mobile dev also, I just find it difficult to apply cross language programming no need to explain what AJAX call is about.

Comment: Well, try something like make the button call a function which makes an ajax call to the url, and the url is where you are trying to pass the info.

Comment: isn't it too much just for getting the id? just sayin'